# 14.04 Login loop - DMs don't work but gnome-session works from xterm - No Nvidia

Tags: 14.04, login, gnome-session

Lots of posts related to **login loop** issues. However, none of the solutions work.

1. .Xauthority file has permissions `-rw------- 1 mangouser mangouser`
2. /tmp folder has permissions `drwxrwxrwt  16 root root`
3. Removed all **nvidia** drivers
4. Disk size seems to be fine

   `udev            3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /dev
   tmpfs           772M  1.9M  770M   1% /run
   /dev/sda3       275G   55G  206G  22% /
   none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
   none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
   none            3.8G  268M  3.6G   7% /run/shm
   none            100M   24K  100M   1% /run/user
   /dev/sda5       184G  142G   33G  82% /var
   /dev/sda6       184G  173G  933M 100% /home`
5. .xsession-errors file contains

   `Xsession: X session started for mangouser at Thu Sep 29 11:19:28 NPT 2016
   localuser:mangouser being added to access control list
   Script for ibus started at run_im`
6. Tried with all the users in the system, and switching all available display managers (gdm, lightdm, kdm, lxdm)

However, I am login and run `xinit` from tty1, open the xterm shell, and start gnome-session from the shell.

Could someone please try to identify what has been overlooked ?

Comment: "Disk size seems to be fine" - but I see `100% /home`?

Comment: /home has around 1GB remaining ~ 933M